# MongoDB Aggregation - return default value for documents that don't match query

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I'm having trouble figuring out the right aggregation pipe operations to return the results I need.

I have a collection similar to the following :-

```
{
    "_id" : "writer1",
    "Name" : "writer1",
    "Website" : "website1",
    "Reviews" : [
            {
                    "Film" : {
                            "Name" : "Jurassic Park",
                            "Genre" : "Action"
                    },
                    "Score" : 4
            },
            {
                    "Technology" : {
                            "Name" : "Mad Max",
                             "Genre" : "Action"
                    },
                    "Score" : 5
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "writer2",
    "Name" : "writer2",
    "Website" : "website1",
    "Reviews" : [           
            {
                    "Technology" : {
                            "Name" : "Mad Max",
                             "Genre" : "Action"
                    },
                    "Score" : 5
            }
    ]
}
```

And this is my aggregation so far : -

```
db.writers.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$Reviews" },
    { "$match" : { "Reviews.Film.Name" : "Jurassic Park" } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$Website" , "score" : { "$avg" : "$Reviews.Score" },
        writers :{ $push: { name:"$Name", score:"$Reviews.Score" } }
    }}
])
```

This returns only writers who have a review of the matching film and also only websites that have at least 1 writer who has reviewed the film, 
however, I need to return all websites containing a list of their all writers, with a score of 0 if they haven't written a review for the specified film.

so, I am currently getting : -

```
{ "_id" : "website1", "score" : 4, "writers" : [ { "name" : "writer1", "score" : 4 } ] }
```

When I actually need : -

```
{ "_id" : "website1", "score" : 2, "writers" : [ { "name" : "writer1", "score" : 4 },{ "name" :"writer2", "score" : 0 } ] }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: What you are asking here is "kind of possible" but seriously speaking, "It's a bit nuts". How do we know who your writers are? Please honestly think about this. If there is no "writer3' for example in any of the data, but somewhere you deem "writer3" to exist, then where do we get that from? At any rate, you are better off manipulating "not there" data in "post processing" rather than throwing this at the aggregation framework. Just like with SQL queries. There are many things you "can" do, but the real question is "should I really be doing this?". My answer is no, you should not.

Comment: it's not that the writer does not exist, it is there but my aggregation does not return it as the writer does not have a review for the film specified in the $match, this results in the incorrect average score calculation.

Comment: Please grasp the concept here. Adding data "that does not exist" should be done in "post processing". Throwing in a list of "possible writers" creating "zero score results" on the server end will slow things down considerably. So even if there is a "writers" collection to source from, and there are 10 writers and only 1 or 2 reviewed a film, it is not efficient to throw all 10 at the server to produce results for. This should be simple to understand. Add them to your results with 0 scores when they are not part of the results returned. Much more efficient, and sooo much simplier.

Comment: Ahh, I see where you are coming from now, sorry for being dense! I'll give it a rethink, thanks.